# Does this Monte Carlo method evidence the consistency of an estimator?

Tags: bootstrap, simulation, monte-carlo, consistency

**The Statistic**

Let $\hat{\theta}(x)$ be a statistical estimator of population parameter $\theta$ whose exact distribution is unknown. Let $\hat{\theta}_n(x)$ be the estimator calculate from a sample of size $n$. Assume continuity of the random variable $X$, and the estimator, if needed.

**Monte Carlo Method**

1. Generate a data set $D$ of instances of $X$ of size $k$.
2. Calculate $\hat{\theta}_k(x)$ from $D$.
3. Define $D$ as the population of interest, with true parameter $\hat{\theta}_k(x) = \theta$.
4. Bootstrap $D$ with sample sizes $n = \{1, 2, \cdots, k\}$, calling each sample $S_n$.
5. Calculate $\hat{\theta}_k(x)$ from each $S_n$.
6. Plot $|\theta - \hat{\theta}_k(x)|$ against $n$.
7. Interpret whether the plot shows convergence.

**Example**

Let's say we wishes to give some evidence that the Pearson's product-moment correlation coefficient is consistent, ignoring that for bivariate Gaussian distributions it is symbolically provable. Here is a quick example of the procedure (with added replication at a given sample size).

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import pearsonr
from sklearn.utils import resample

N = 1000
X = np.random.normal(0,100,size=N*2).reshape(N, 2)
X[:,1] = 10*X[:,0] + np.random.normal(0,10,size=N)

theta, p = pearsonr(X[:,0],X[:,1]) 
print('"True" Correlation', theta)


sample_sizes = []
estimates = []

for k in range(2, N+1):
    for i in range(10):
        bsx = resample(X,n_samples=k)
        estimates.append(pearsonr(bsx[:,0], bsx[:,1])[0])
        sample_sizes.append(k)

estimates = np.abs(np.array(estimates) - theta)
plt.scatter(sample_sizes, estimates)
plt.xlabel('Subsample Size (k)')
plt.ylabel(r'$|\theta - \hat{\theta}_k|$')
plt.show()
```

Which printed `"True" Correlation 0.9999517492601357`, and produced the following plot.

[image]

**Question**

While I can see there are parameters like the population sample size, and the number of replicates for each subsample size, does this approach give compelling evidence that a given statistic is consistent?

**Edit 1**

I've remade the plot, but (1) lowered the alpha channel on the point, (2) added a black line for the mean of the estimated bias at a given sample size, and (3) added red lines for the plus-or-minus standard deviation of the estimated bias.
[image]

Comment: You could use a log-scale on the error to improve the readability and repeat the experiment many times to show the variability and its decrease in $k$ over the bootstrap draws.